# What is the best way to debug algolia.log and Algolia errors in system.log files?

Tags: algolia

We are running Algolia 1.5.2 in our Magento store, things seem to have been running fine for months now. On a routine site check I noticed that the algolia.log file and system.log file are growing at an alarming rate. Thousands of errors a day in the system.log. All the same:

```
2016-04-28T13:51:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array to string conversion/mnt/nfs/www.ourdomain.com/files/html/app/code/community/Algolia/Algoliasearch/Helper/Entity/Producthelper.php  )
```

And the algolia.log file is growing at almost the same rate but with this error

```
2016-04-28T22:18:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): >>>>> BEGIN CREATE RECORD 10512 1 (Our Site)
2016-04-28T22:18:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): Product type (bundle, mapped to: bundle)
2016-04-28T22:18:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): <<<<< END CREATE RECORD 10512 1 (Our Site) (0.10960912704468sec)
2016-04-28T22:18:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): <<<<< END CREATE RECORDS 1 (Our Site) (0.10998892784119sec))
```

It's unclear to us if this is just a normal feature with the Algolia debug? Is there a way to turn off debug? Is there a "best debug method" for these issues. It seems that thousands of repeated errors a day has to be a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: The best is probably to open a new GitHub issue on the official repository to ask the main contributors: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/issues